# Replace mysqli_num_rows with fetchColumn PDO >=1

Tags: php, sql

I'm having a problem with this. Basicly I want to replace if(mysqli_num_rows($result_password)>=1){ with the second code

```
<?php
class DataBase {

    private $DB_HOST = DBHOST;
    private $DB_NAME = DBNAME;
    private $DB_USER = DBUSER;
    private $DB_PASS = DBPASS;
    private $PDO;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->PDO = new PDO("mysql:host=".$this->DB_HOST."; dbname=".$this->DB_NAME, $this->DB_USER, $this->DB_PASS, array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"));
    }
    public function select($query, $bindings = []) {
        $STH = $this->PDO->prepare($query);
        $STH->execute($bindings);
        $result = $STH->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        return $result ? $result : false;
    }

    public function query($query, $bindings = []){
        $STH = $this->PDO->prepare($query);
        return $STH->execute($bindings);
    }

    public function selectOne($query, $bindings = []) {
        $STH = $this->PDO->prepare($query);
        $STH->execute($bindings);
        $result = $STH->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        return $result ? $result : false;
    }

}
```

And im trying to replace `if(mysqli_num_rows($pw_result )>=1)`{ with this:

```
if ($pw_result = $conn->query($pw_query)) {

    if ($pw_result->fetchColumn() >=1) {
```

Missing query:

```
$pw_query = "SELECT password FROM passwords WHERE password='$valid' AND executed='no'";
```

But it keeps giving me this error: Fatal error: Call to a member function fetchColumn() on boolean

I know there is a lots of posts with this, but I already search and couldn't find it, that is why im here, and maybe is very simple.

Comment: $pw_result is false, which means your query failed. Check for [PDO errors](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php) after your query.

Comment: @aynber i dont think so, i will put my query

Comment: You could be running into quoting issues, or it could be another issue entirely. Without the generated query and the database schema, it's hard to tell. Check for [PDO errors](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php) to see what's going on.

Comment: I don't understand what you're wanting to do here. You're using PDO stuff but then wanting to replace `mysqli_num_rows` with `fetchColumn()`. You're then using `$conn->query` but that doesn't correspond with the PDO connection method. Sounds like you're mixing mysql apis here. How you're using that class is unknown.

Answer (score 0):

Your `DataBase::query()` method is returning the result of `$STH->execute()`, which will always be [a `true` / `false` success indicator](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php#refsect1-pdostatement.execute-returnvalues).

If you want to use the result of the query, the function should return `$STH` instead.